# How do I use the default value, which is in a switch statement, in an "if "statement for validation?

Tags: java

Here is the switch statement which is in another class:

```
    public int calcPoints(char grade)
    {
      int points;
      switch(grade)
     {
       case 'A':
        points = 4; break;
       case 'a': 
        points = 4; break;
       case 'B':
        points = 3; break;
       case 'b':
        points = 3; break;
       case 'C':
        points = 2; break;
       case 'c':
        points = 2; break;
       case 'D':
        points = 1; break;
       case 'd':
        points = 1; break;
       case 'F':
        points = 0; break;
       case 'f':
        points = 0; break;
       default: 
        points = -1; break;    
       }
      return points;
      }
```

Here is where the if statement is located (highlighted with comment):

```
      do
      {
        System.out.print("Enter grade (one character): ");
        aGrade = in.next();
        grade = aGrade.charAt(0);
        if(aGrade.length() != 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid grade - must be exactly one character!");
        }
        else if(aGrade.equals(-1)) //This is where I want to use the default value
                                   //Obviously (-1) won't work
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid grade - must enter A,B,C,D,F");
        }
      }
      while(aGrade.length() != 1 ||(aGrade.equals(-1))); //I want to use it here too.
```

I have indicated exactly where I want to use the value with comments above. How do I use the default value from the switch statement if there is a way.

Comment: Where are you using your `calcPoints` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change that line to

```
else if(calcPoints(grade) == -1)
```

Answer (score 3):

use   `else if(calcPoints(grade) == -1))` instead of   `else if(aGrade.equals(-1))`

To compare two primitive datatype use `"=="` this one

Comment: Wrong.  `aGrade` is a `String` here.

Comment: How could appending `'0'` to the end of a `String` possibly ever turn it into `-1` ?  That must be some magic String you've got there!

Answer (score 1):

Since `aGrade` is a String, you need to compare it with a String as well

```
else if(aGrade.equals("-1"))
...
while(aGrade.length() != 1 ||(aGrade.equals("-1")));
```

`"-1"` - This is a String having the value -1. You have to use this to compare it with your `aGrade` String.

`-1` - This is an `int` having the value -1.

---

But you seem to be doing something else here. I guess you need this

```
else if(calcPoints(grade) == -1)
```

This will call the `calcPoints()` method with the `grade` character you get from the user input and return the points for that. This points is now an `int` which you need to compare using the `==` and not the `equals()` method, as primitive data types are compared using the `==` operator.